# How I can stretch my display resolution?

Tags: display-resolution

> Acer Aspire 5750

Hi I want know how to stretch my display resolution. Because if I use 1024 by 768 it shows black bars. How I can stretch my resolution? (I use Kubuntu 19.04)Thanks! :).
Edit: How I show the photos. I'm Italian but I think that you can understand. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wON1.jpg ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2Pm.jpg
2°Edit: Specs :
i3-2310M
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 3000
RAM:4GB DDR3
HDD:500GB (with win8.1 dualboot)

Comment: could you uninstall and reinstall the graphics driver first? it's not normal that you don't have your exact screen resolution as an option. no matter what it is ubuntu should suggest it (and even default to it). also please attach a screenshot of your display options with the resolution drop-down menu opened.

Comment: What is your monitor make and model?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have a laptop

Comment: What is your laptop make and model?

Comment: @tatsu I have the correct res of my laptop (1366x768). I will post a pic ASAP.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Acer Aspire 5750